# How Sequence Diagram model Dynamic Structure?

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram, argouml

Could anyone Help me with the following question, this question is for five marks. I scored only three marks. Can anyone help me with it

Class Diagrams model the static structure of the system. Explain how Sequence Diagrams model the dynamic structure of the system.

My current answer was :

Class diagram shows the structure of the system that is the objects found in the system. sequence diagram shows how objects interact with each other by making use of lifelines and activation bars.

Can anyone give me a better answer? Thanks

Comment: Only your instructor could really tell you what they were looking for for full credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To score fully you need to mention messages (sync, async and return) and that they correspond to class methods. Messages can show the pure operation signature and/or concrete parameters.

Also, lifelines correspond to instances. That is, they are real examples of scenarios which need to be highlighted.

As bonus: you can show timing constraints for messages.